# IIS rewrite rule to deny access files and folder starting with "."

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I need an IIS rewrite rule to deny access to all files and folder starting with "."

Files like
.git
.composer
.htaccess  (I know is for Apache )

Any folder like
/.test/
A plus if rule can cover any folder starting with “.”  but  not this one “./well-known/acme-challenge”

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I found it ;)

add this to **web.config** make sure the <**rule**> is inside <**rules**>

```
<rules>

...

   <rule name="Deny files and folderd starting with ." patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="(^\.|\/\.)" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
     </conditions>
     <action type="AbortRequest" />
  </rule>


<rules>
```